# Standard errors of OLS estimate if regressor is a stochast?

Tags: least-squares, conditional-expectation, unbiased-estimator

Assume the model classical linear regression model (with for simplicity only one regressor)
$$y=X\beta +u,$$

with $u$, $X$ independent, and $\operatorname{Var}(u|X)=\sigma^2I_n$. Assume for simplicity that $X$ only contains one explanatory variable and no intercept. But **assume that $X$ is a stochast**, and is i.i.d. normally distributed.

We take the standard OLS estimate $\hat \beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. **What is the correct standard error for $\hat \beta$?**

### If $X$ were non-stochastic:

To calculate the standard error *if $X$ were not a stochast*, then we could simply calculate $Var(\hat \beta|X)=\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$. We can then calculate the standard error as follows: $$se_{\hat \beta}=\sqrt {\hat {\operatorname{Var}}(\hat \beta|X)}=\sqrt{\hat \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}}$$

Where $\hat \sigma^2=\frac {\hat u ^T\hat u}{n-1}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$.

### But if $X$ is stochastic:

**However, since $X$ is a stochast, it seems to me that calculating $se_{\beta}$ in this manner is wrong for this model.**

It seems to me that we instead need the **unconditional** variance:
$$se_{\hat \beta}=\sqrt {\hat {Var}(\hat \beta)}$$

That means we need to use the law of total variance:

$$\operatorname{Var}(\hat \beta)= E(\operatorname{Var}(\hat \beta |X))+\operatorname{Var}(E(\hat \beta|X))=E(\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1})+\operatorname{Var}(\beta)=\sigma^2E((X^TX)^{-1})+0$$

We can then for our standard error use an estimate of this, which is simply the same as in the non-stochastic case: $$\hat \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1}$$

**However, I'm not entirely sure if this last step is correct. Can we just estimate $E[(X^TX)^{-1}]$ with $(X^TX)^{-1}$? How do we know that this is an unbiased estimate? And even if it is, how do we know that the product $\hat \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1}$ we get by multiplying it with our estimate of $\sigma^2$ will be an unbiased estimate of the population product $\sigma^2E((X^TX)^{-1})$ (since expectations of products are not generally equal to products of expectations)?**